# Extract all text between two specific empty divs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have html that looks like the one shown below. I want the text between the innermost two empty divs with class name "start" and "end" respectively. In the code below - I want the text between **2nd** `<div class ="start"> </div>` and the **first** `<div class ="end"> </div>`  In between these 2 empty divs there can be multiple divs with any number of tags, and I want the text in these divs. I tried accessing the text, multiple ways using just `div.attrs['class']` and `find_next_siblings` methods, but it did not work. How to go about this?

```
many <divs> </divs> and other tags

<div class ="start"> </div>
<div> bla bla bla </div>

<div class ="start"> </div>
<div> <i> <a> <span> <p> Text I want </p></span></a></i> </div>
<div> <p> Text I want </p> <p> Text I want </p> </div>
<div class ="end"></div>

<div> bla bla bla </div>
<div class ="end"></div>

many <divs> </divs> and other tags
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get the text you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
many <divs> </divs> and other tags

<div class ="start"> </div>
<div> bla bla bla </div>

<div class ="start"> </div>
<div> <i> <a> <span> <p> Text I want </p></span></a></i> </div>
<div> <p> Text I want </p> <p> Text I want </p> </div>
<div class ="end"></div>

<div> bla bla bla </div>
<div class ="end"></div>

many <divs> </divs> and other tags
'''
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
start_item = soup.select('div[class="start"]')[-1]

for x in start_item.find_next_siblings():
    x_class = x.get('class')[0] if x.get('class') else None
    if x_class != 'end':       
        print('Wanted text:', x.text)
        
    else:
        print('reached the end')
        break
```

Result in terminal:

```
Wanted text:      Text I want  
Wanted text:   Text I want   Text I want  
reached the end
```

See BeautifulSoup documentation [here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

To get the tags between the last `class ="start"` and first `class ="end"` tags, you can use either [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with [CSS selectors](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/combinators/#general-sibling-combinator) or [`.find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) with the [`lambda`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) function

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
pasted_html = '''many<divs></divs>and other tags<div class="start"></div><div>bla bla bla</div><div class="start"></div><div><i><a><span><p>Text I want</p></span></a></i></div><div><p>Text I want</p><p>Text I want</p></div><div class="end"></div><div>bla bla bla</div><div class="end"></div>many<divs></divs>and other tags'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(pasted_html, 'html5lib')
```

<sub>Parsing with `html5lib` is more reliable if using `.select`, but you can use a different parser if you go with `.find`.</sub>

<sub>**Please note that this will not return anything unless the last `.start` comes *before* the first `.end`.**</sub>

Using `.select`

```py
s, e = 'div.start', 'div.end' 
mTags = soup.select(f'{s}:not(:has(~ {s})) ~ *:not({e}):not({e} ~ *):has(~ {e})')
```

should give you the same ResultSet as when you use `.find_all`

```py
mTags = soup.find_all(
    lambda t: t.find_previous_sibling('div', {'class': 'start'}) and
    not t.find_next_sibling('div', {'class': 'start'}) and
    t.find_next_sibling('div', {'class': 'end'}) and
    not t.find_previous_sibling('div', {'class': 'end'})
)
```

(I prefer `.select` just because the code is shorter.)

---

To extract the text, you can either join the texts from each tag in `mTags`

```py
mText = ' '.join([t.get_text(' ').strip() for t in mTags])
# mText = "Text I want Text I want     Text I want"
```

or you can join the htmls and parse again before using `.get_text` (less efficient)

```py
mText = BeautifulSoup(
    '\n'.join([t.prettify().strip() for t in mTags])
).get_text(' ').strip()
# mText = "Text I want\n     \n \n \n \n \n \n \n  Text I want\n  \n \n  Text I want"
```

---

If you want to minimize whitespace you can do something like

```py
mText = ' '.join(w for w in mText.split() if w)
```

then `mText` should be `"Text I want Text I want Text I want"` no matter which of the above approaches were used.